# How do I avoid tags wrapping and display the tags in one line using jQuery TagIt plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tag-it

I want to avoid tags wrapping and display the tags in one line using jQuery TagIt plugin.
I created a TagIt input element using steps in [this](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it) repository.

**Here is my preview:**
[image]

But I want it to display all the tags in a single line without wrapping and maybe use a scroll bar instead.

**Minimal reproduceable example:**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="h-100">

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aehlke/tag-it@2.0/js/tag-it.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jquery-ui-bootstrap/jquery-ui-bootstrap/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aehlke/tag-it/css/jquery.tagit.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#mintTags").tagit();
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="hidden" name="mint-numbers" id="mintTags">
</body>
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include the (relevant "*[mcve]*") code to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using such an ancient version of jQuery? And - with an [mcve] demo (see: "*[I've been told to create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets". How do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/82548)*") we require you to put the relevant minimal code together, posting the actual code and *not* "<!-- include the 5 links from above -->"). Also, what's the source of the tags generated with the plugin?

Comment: @DavidThomas I reedited the code. I am using the same version of jQuery because the repo uses it and it doesn't work with newer versions. I'm not clear what you mean by "source". The tags can be entered as input by user.

Comment: I've added a Snippet so that your code can be run in the question itself, there is an error - obviously due to the non-working script src (this is almost certainly correct in your local implementation, but links to nothing here on SO). By "source" I meant, what causes the tagit plugin to generate the 'tags'? It seems that users enter text, but you don't show anywhere that they do this, so far as I can see. My apologies for the ongoing questions, I'm trying to help you get enough relevant information in your question so that we can actually help you.

Comment: @DavidThomas Hi, Thank You so much for replying. I was going to give up, because I felt like a newb and this wasn't worth it. But I just found out how life saving jsdelivr is and I got my hopes back up. Thanks for being kind and pointing out to me how to make the code runnable on the site itself.

Comment: @DavidThomas Please help me out. I have been stuck at this for so long and spent way too much time here looking for an answer. I know it doesn't pay you but this is a genuine request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a display flex to the tagit `ul` element.

Here is an example of css that will make the list scrollable, depending on the new input class (`tagit-nowrap`).

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="h-100">

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aehlke/tag-it@2.0/js/tag-it.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jquery-ui-bootstrap/jquery-ui-bootstrap/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aehlke/tag-it/css/jquery.tagit.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#mintTags").tagit();
    });
  </script>
  <style>
     .tagit-nowrap + .tagit{
      display: flex;
     }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <input class="tagit-nowrap" type="hidden" name="mint-numbers" id="mintTags">
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you are a life saver. I must be such a newb to know that display: flex; would solve the issue.